# How to test React component with AJAX in componentWillMount

Tags: reactjs, redux, jestjs

I have a React component where some data is fetched via HTTP during `componentWillMount`.
This is done pretty much like explained [here](https://redux.js.org/advanced/asyncactions) using the [Redux Thunk middleware](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk).
The request is done with [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios).
So initially a `loading` state is set and the data will be set as soon as the request returns.

```
class SomeComponent extends Component {
    //...

    componentWillMount() {
        store.dispatch(fetchInitialData())
    }
    // ...
}
```

The action doing the fetch:

```
export function fetchInitialData() {
    return dispatch => {
        return axios.get('https://our.api')
            .then(res => {
                dispatch(handleSuccess(res.data));
            })
            .catch(error => dispatch(handleError(error)));
    }
}
```

The test is written with Jest and Enzyme and axios is mocked with [axios-mock-adapter](https://github.com/ctimmerm/axios-mock-adapter).

```
import Enzyme, { mount } from 'enzyme'
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16'
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store'
import axios from 'axios'
import MockAdapter from 'axios-mock-adapter'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import response from 'testdata/api/response.json'

Enzyme.configure({
    adapter: new Adapter()
});

function createMockStore() {
    const mockStore = configureMockStore([thunk]);
    return mockStore({});
}

describe('some component', () => {
    it('should render ...', () => {
        const mock = new MockAdapter(axios);
        mock.onGet('/our.api').reply(200, response);

        const store = createMockStore();

        const enzymeWrapper = mount(<SomeComponent store={store}/>);

        console.log('enzymeWrapper', enzymeWrapper.html());
    });
});
```

The problem is that the html of `enzymeWrapper` always contains only the representation of the initial state. The initial HTML never changes according to the new state from the response.
When I add logging to the reducers and services I see that the mocked requests executes and the state is filled with the mocked response.
But the component does not re-render with the new state data.

I want to point out that this is only an issue in the test. In the actual app everything works fine.

To me it seems that I need to somehow wait for the state changes to get applied. But I don't know how.

Comment: Just a quick tip in your action creator you should emit the catch block because if a component throws during dispatch your catch block is gonna catch it. you should append another function to handle the error like this `export function fetchInitialData() {
  return dispatch => {
    return axios.get('https://our.api')
      .then(
        res => dispatch(handleSuccess(res.data)),
        error => dispatch(handleError(error))
      )
  }
}`

Comment: The problem is there's no promise to chain to wait for mocked request to be completed. This is at least possible by testing them in separation, i.e. `fetchInitialData` can be tested directly or with redux-mock-store, and the component can be tested with mocked `fetchInitialData`. Makes sense because they are different units. I wonder if there are tools to make this easier.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I might try that but in general we like to test whole (connected) components because we feel that this gives us more confidence in our test. We used to mock too much stuff.

Comment: @LazerBass This 'confidence' is actually considered wrong test strategy if you write unit tests. A proper way to test a unit is to mock every other unit. What you're talking about are integration tests. Most times they are not needed if you have unit test coverage. And e2e tests allow to augment unit tests by testing how the thing works in whole without going into details.

Comment: `jest.runAllTicks()` may help to finish all pending promises(that a currently fullfilled after test has already been finished). But I agree that it's better to test component and action creator independently